# Parallel line in a non isosceles trapezoid cuts of equal segements

Tags: geometry

Given the following trapezoid:
[image: non isosceles trapezoid]

Prove that FG = HI.

The following I know: In triangle ACD: $CD/AD = FG/AG$ In triangle CDB: $CD/CB = HI/HB$ After that I'm lost

Comment: What have you tried?  What was your difficulty?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE! Problem Statement Questions are usually frowned upon on this site. Please include some context. This can be anything: your attempts to solve this problem, the story about how did you come up with this problem, etc... Just something that will make it not look like copypasta from some textbook.

Comment: The following I know:
In triangle ACD: CD/AD = FG/AG
In triangle CDB: CD/CB = HI/HB
After that I'm lost

Comment: @JosvanWeert, it would be a really good idea to include this to the body of the question by clicking on the "edit" button under your post. Not everyone reads comments...

Comment: Sorry, I will do it next time. For now I have an answer. Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By repeated usage of the theorem of the three parallel lines and two secants: $$CD:FG=AD:AG=CB:BH=CD:IH$$

Therefore $CD:FG=CD:IH$, implying $IH\cong FG$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $$\frac{FG}{CD}=\frac{AF}{AC}=\frac{BI}{BD}=\frac{HI}{CD}.$$